# How can i use my EC2 Elastic IP address as proxy server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, elastic-ip

Please i need help in using elastic IP(assigned to instance) from AWS as proxy server, the first picture shows how other people are doing it. Users on my website will use it to login to another website that requires static IP(Doesn't change). I want to know how to authenticate EC2 elastic IP and use it as proxy server, all i have so far is i need to assign elastic IP to my instance on AWS, but i don't know how to authenticate the IPs once created. And i don't want to buy static IP from other company like brightdata or smartproxy.

This picture shows how other people are doing it, and the IP is from amazon:

[image: This picture shows how other people are doing it, and the IP is from amazon]

Answer (score 0):

Does your Public IP change that often? Can you just have them give you their 'IP Chicken' address and just use that?

I think based on what you are describing you want to whitelist IPs via an ACL. Here are some steps you can use:
https://www.purevpn.com/blog/whitelist-ip-addresses-on-aws/

If you do not want to use their Public IP from wherever they are, here is another workflow:

VPN to a Bastion Host (Jump Host)
Put the Public IP you whitelist to your application on the Jump host
Require your users access the Jump Host to access the website.

You can Use Amazon Elastic IPs without issue. It is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Public IP addresses from AWS can only be used on AWS services (eg Amazon EC2 instances). They *cannot* be used on external services outside of AWS.

In your picture, the IP address is assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: I have updated the question, its not public IP, i t is elastic IP, from my research, it is possible to buy elastic IP and not assign it ti EC2 instance and you will be charged for this unlike when you assign it to an instance

Comment: Yes, an Elastic IP address is a static public IP address that can be assigned to Amazon EC2 instances, NAT Gateways and Application Load Balancers (and a few other things, I think). Once created, an Elastic IP address can be assigned to one of these resources. The charge of half a cent per hour only applies if it is _not_ attached, or it is attached to a resource that is not running. However, I cannot understand what you are asking about "authenticating" the IP address. Can you explain more about that?

Comment: https://createproxy.com lets you create proxy using your AWS account, they create couple of instances and create IP using those instances, and then you can use this IP, insert it into you browsers settings and surf masking your real IP. and i think its up to 5 IP per one instance, so 10  instance means 50 IPs. and this also confirms what you said "In your picture, the IP address is assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance.". So the question is how can i use my elastic instance IP as proxy server.